# Microsoft AAD Group - get members of 'group' type using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is there a way to get only members of type **'microsoft.graph.group'** on running [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[groupid]/transitivemembers/microsoft.graph.group](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%5Bgroupid%5D/transitivemembers/microsoft.graph.group) in C#? The below code:

```
            var members = graphClient.Groups[objectId.ToString()].Members.Request().GetAsync()
                                    .ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            do
            {
                var directoryObjects = members.CurrentPage.ToList();
                foreach (var member in directoryObjects)
                {
                    if (member is Microsoft.Graph.User)
                    {                        
                        var a = new AzureADUser { ObjectId = Guid.Parse((member as Microsoft.Graph.User).Id) };
                        users.Add(a);
                    }
                    else if (member is Microsoft.Graph.Group)
                    {
                        var b = Guid.Parse((member as Microsoft.Graph.Group).Id);
                        groups.Add(b);
                    }
                }
            }
            while (members.NextPageRequest != null && (members = members.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()).Count > 0);
```

returns all types of members and I have to check the type of each member to get the list of groups. Is there a way to make the graph call to return only members of type **'microsoft.graph.group'**? If that's possible, is the cost associated to call graph to get all members v/s members of type 'microsoft.graph.group' the same?

Answer (score 0):

For checking the List group transitive members you can Use the microsoft.graph.group OData cast to get only members that are groups:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};

var group = await graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"].TransitiveMembers
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
    .GetAsync();
```

Please refer this document for more details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-3-use-the-microsoftgraphgroup-odata-cast-to-get-only-members-that-are-groups.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ThANk you! I tried this already but it provides all members not just groups.